# Evaluation of $ \int_{-k}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos k}}dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluation of $$\displaystyle \int_{-k}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos k}}dx\;,$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-k}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos k}}dx = 2\int_{0}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-\cos k}}dx$$

Now Substiute $$\displaystyle \cos x = \frac{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}\;,$$ So we get $$\displaystyle I = 2\int_{0}^{k}\frac{\sec \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}-\cos k(1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2})}}dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = 2\int_{0}^{k}\frac{\sec \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{(1-\cos k)-(1+\cos k)\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}}dx = 2\int_{0}^{k}\frac{\sec \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2\sin^2\frac{k}{2}-2\cos^2 \frac{k}{2}\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}}dx$$

Now How can I solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: u will need elliptic functions for this one

Comment: $$\int_{-k}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos(k)}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{4\text{F}\left(\frac{k}{2}|\csc^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(k)}}\space,\Re(k)>0\space\space\text{&&}\space\space\Im(k)=0$$

So:

$$k\in\mathbb{R^+}$$

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to continue from your method but before that let me post my method:

use substitution $$\sqrt{cosx-cosk}=t$$ so $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{cosx-cosk}}=\frac{-2dt}{sinx}=\frac{-2dt}{\sqrt{1-(t^2+cosk)^2}}=\frac{-2dt}{\sqrt{1-(t^2+cosk)}\sqrt{1+(t^2+cosk)}}=\frac{-2dt}{\sqrt{2sin^2\frac{k}{2}-t^2}\sqrt{2cos^2\frac{k}{2}+t^2}}$$

if we let $a=\sqrt{2}sin\frac{k}{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}cos\frac{k}{2}$ we have

$$I=\int\frac{-2dt}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}\sqrt{b^2+t^2}}$$ which wolfram gives as

[image]

Comment: as long as tge square roots stay real u could simplify ur last equality nicely