# Is there any way to evaluate/ estimate this integral apart from wolfram?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am looking for a way to evaluate (if not, then estimate) the following $$\int_0^x \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{\cos t - \cos x}}dt, \ 0 < x \leq \pi$$

Wolfram tells me that it blows up at $x = \pi$ and for lower values, it does not. (I tried $\pi/2$ and $\pi/3$.)

---

Edit 1

I have tried to make use of comparing the integrand with some other function, whose behaviour is known. For $\cos t - \cos x$, I am trying with $t-x$, but once it goes inside the root, then the range no longer stays real.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: thanks, I have included my attempt to solve the question.

Comment: Using https://approach0.xyz/ search engine on formulas, you find a lot of other identical questions, like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1544418 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2058253 ...

Answer (score 0):

Maple does this as an elliptic integral.  If $0 < x < \pi$,
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {\cos \left( t \right) -\cos \left( x
 \right) }}}\,{\rm d}t=\sqrt {2}\;{\rm F} \left({\frac {2\sin
 \left( x/2 \right) }{\sqrt {2-2\,\cos \left( x \right) }}},
\frac{\sqrt {2-2\,\cos \left( x \right) }}{2} \right) 
$$
The graph:

[image: A]
There is a vertical aspymptote as $x \to \pi^-$.